# ReflectionException no detectado: la clase "env" no existe

Tags: php, laravel-8, consola

```
#NO ME FUNCIONA NINGUN COMANDO CON LA PALABRA ARTISAN#
#NO LO SOLUCIONO COMPOSER DUMP-AUTOLOAD#
#NO LO RESOLVIO COMPOSER UPDATE#
#NO ES TELESCOPE=FALSE#
#NO SON ESPACIOS EN BLANCO EN EL NOMBRE DE LA APLICACION .ENV#
```

las vistas del proyecto funcionan, y en otros proyectos el comando artisan funciona con normalidad.

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ReflectionException: Class "env" does not
> exist in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\gsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:877
> Stack trace:
> #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\gsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(877):
> ReflectionClass->__construct('env')
> #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\gsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(758):
> Illuminate\Container\Container->build('env')
> #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\gsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(841):
> Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('env', Array, true)
> #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\gsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(694):
> Illuminate\Foundation\Application->resolve('env', Array)
> #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\gsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(826):
> Illuminate\Container\Container->make('env', Array)
> #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\gsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(1423):
> Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('env')
> #6 C:\xampp\htdocs\gsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(631):
> Illuminate\Container\Container->offsetGet('env')
> #7 C:\xampp\htdocs\gsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Log\LogManager.php(523):
> Illuminate\Foundation\Application->runningUnitTests()
> #8 C:\xampp\htdocs\gsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Log\LogManager.php(109):
> Illuminate\Log\LogManager->parseDriver(NULL)
> #9 C:\xampp\htdocs\gsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Log\LogManager.php(581):
> Illuminate\Log\LogManager->driver()
> #10 C:\xampp\htdocs\gsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler.php(252):
> Illuminate\Log\LogManager->error('Illuminate\Rout...', Array)
> #11 C:\xampp\htdocs\gsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel.php(366):
> Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler->report(Object(TypeError))
> #12 C:\xampp\htdocs\gsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel.php(131):
> Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->reportException(Object(TypeError))
> #13 C:\xampp\htdocs\gsapp\artisan(37): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput),
> Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
> #14 {main}
>
> Next Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException: Target
> class [env] does not exist. in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\gsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:879
> Stack trace:
> #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\gsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(758):
> Illuminate\Container\Container->build('env')
> #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\gsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(841):
> Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('env', Array, true)
> #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\gsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(694):
> Illuminate\Foundation\Application->resolve('env', Array)
> #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\gsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(826):
> Illuminate\Container\Container->make('env', Array)
> #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\gsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(1423):
> Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('env')
> #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\gsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(631):
> Illuminate\Container\Container->offsetGet('env')
> #6 C:\xampp\htdocs\gsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Log\LogManager.php(523):
> Illuminate\Foundation\Application->runningUnitTests()
> #7 C:\xampp\htdocs\gsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Log\LogManager.php(109):
> Illuminate\Log\LogManager->parseDriver(NULL)
> #8 C:\xampp\htdocs\gsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Log\LogManager.php(581):
> Illuminate\Log\LogManager->driver()
> #9 C:\xampp\htdocs\gsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler.php(252):
> Illuminate\Log\LogManager->error('Illuminate\Rout...', Array)
> #10 C:\xampp\htdocs\gsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel.php(366):
> Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler->report(Object(TypeError))
> #11 C:\xampp\htdocs\gsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel.php(131):
> Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->reportException(Object(TypeError))
> #12 C:\xampp\htdocs\gsapp\artisan(37): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput),
> Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
> #13 {main}   thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\gsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php
> on line 879
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught ReflectionException: Class "env" does not exist
> in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\gsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:877
> Stack trace:
> #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\gsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(877):
> ReflectionClass->__construct('env')
> #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\gsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(758):
> Illuminate\Container\Container->build('env')
> #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\gsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(841):
> Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('env', Array, true)
> #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\gsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(694):
> Illuminate\Foundation\Application->resolve('env', Array)
> #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\gsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(826):
> Illuminate\Container\Container->make('env', Array)
> #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\gsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(1423):
> Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('env')
> #6 C:\xampp\htdocs\gsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(631):
> Illuminate\Container\Container->offsetGet('env')
> #7 C:\xampp\htdocs\gsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Log\LogManager.php(523):
> Illuminate\Foundation\Application->runningUnitTests()
> #8 C:\xampp\htdocs\gsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Log\LogManager.php(109):
> Illuminate\Log\LogManager->parseDriver(NULL)
> #9 C:\xampp\htdocs\gsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Log\LogManager.php(581):
> Illuminate\Log\LogManager->driver()
> #10 C:\xampp\htdocs\gsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler.php(252):
> Illuminate\Log\LogManager->error('Illuminate\Rout...', Array)
> #11 C:\xampp\htdocs\gsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel.php(366):
> Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler->report(Object(TypeError))
> #12 C:\xampp\htdocs\gsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel.php(131):
> Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->reportException(Object(TypeError))
> #13 C:\xampp\htdocs\gsapp\artisan(37): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput),
> Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
> #14 {main}
>
> Next Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException: Target
> class [env] does not exist. in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\gsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:879
> Stack trace:
> #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\gsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(758):
> Illuminate\Container\Container->build('env')
> #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\gsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(841):
> Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('env', Array, true)
> #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\gsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(694):
> Illuminate\Foundation\Application->resolve('env', Array)
> #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\gsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(826):
> Illuminate\Container\Container->make('env', Array)
> #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\gsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(1423):
> Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('env')
> #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\gsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(631):
> Illuminate\Container\Container->offsetGet('env')
> #6 C:\xampp\htdocs\gsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Log\LogManager.php(523):
> Illuminate\Foundation\Application->runningUnitTests()
> #7 C:\xampp\htdocs\gsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Log\LogManager.php(109):
> Illuminate\Log\LogManager->parseDriver(NULL)
> #8 C:\xampp\htdocs\gsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Log\LogManager.php(581):
> Illuminate\Log\LogManager->driver()
> #9 C:\xampp\htdocs\gsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler.php(252):
> Illuminate\Log\LogManager->error('Illuminate\Rout...', Array)
> #10 C:\xampp\htdocs\gsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel.php(366):
> Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler->report(Object(TypeError))
> #11 C:\xampp\htdocs\gsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel.php(131):
> Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->reportException(Object(TypeError))
> #12 C:\xampp\htdocs\gsapp\artisan(37): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput),
> Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
> #13 {main}   thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\gsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php
> on line 879

Comment: Intuyo que estás haciendo testing en laravel, ¿correcto?

Comment: si, estoy aprendiendo, pero luego que seguí un video para usar git y tener un respaldo, en mi proyecto local dejo de funcionar cualquier comando php artisan, he visto varias formas de "solución" pero ninguno funciona.

Comment: Prueba primero agregando `<env name="TELESCOPE_ENABLED" value="false"/>` a tu phpunit.xml y luego haces, luego agregas la variable telescope en false en tu **env.testing** y limpias todo con `php artisan optimize:clear`, luego`php artisan test --env=testing`

Comment: `<env name="TELESCOPE_ENABLED" value="false"/>` ya esta establecido en el phpunit.xml, lo de agregar la variable en el **env.testing** como lo hago? a ver si despues de eso me funciona algun `php artisan`